# Joomla float form field

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I'm working on a component for Joomla 3.2 which needs the user to input some data in the backend, so somebody before me coded a quite effective configuration form. Now I need to extend it, adding some fields which are required by my functionalities and a couple of the fields should be floats.

Joomla's [standard form field type list](https://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types) doesn't list any "float" field type and [number](https://docs.joomla.org/Number_form_field_type) looks a lot like an integer field to me. There is a way to have number behave like a float or some obscure "float" form type hidden somwehere or should I code the new form type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a float number on the "step" attribute.

Example:

```
<field 
  name="mynumbervalue" 
  type="number" 
  default="0" 
  label="Choose an number" 
  description="" 
  min="0" 
  max="10" 
  step="0.01" />
```